# Problems parsing an XML file with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have to parse xml files which contain entries like

```
<error code="UnknownDevice">
    <description />
</error>
```

which are defined elsewhere as

```
<group name="error definitions">
     <errordef id="0x11" name="UnknownDevice">
        <description>Indicated device is unknown</description>
     </errordef>
     ...
</group>
```

given

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)

tree = ET.parse(inputFileName, parser=parser)
root = tree.getroot()
```

How can I get those values for `errorDef`? I mean the value of `id` and of `description`?

How can I search for & extract those values, using `unknownDevice`?

---

[Update] The error groups have differing names, but always of the format  "XXX error definitions", "YYY error definitions", etc

Further, they seem to be nested at different depths in different documents.

Given the error's title, e.g "unknownDevice", how can I search everything under the root to get the corresponding `id` and `description values?`

Can I go directly to them, using e.g "unknownDevice", or do I have to search first for the error groups?

Comment: Are you using lxml? All current answers assume that (they use the `xpath` method, available in lxml but not in the std lib ElementTree module).

Comment: No I am not (I am so new that I don't even know what it is). I will update the question when I get back to the office, to show what `ET` is. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this:

```
<group name="error definitions">
     <errordef id="0x11" name="UnknownDevice">
        <description>Indicated device is unknown</description>
     </errordef>
     ...
</group>
```

And you want to get the value of `description` and `id` for every `errordef` element, you could do this:

```
for err in tree.xpath('//errordef'):
    print err.get('id'), err.find('description').text
```

Which would give you something like:

```
0x11 Indicated device is unknown
```

Comment: That usually means someone is angry their question got downvoted and is taking it out on everybody else.  C'est la vie here on SO :)

Comment: That's something strange about this thread. I've got two downvotes for a, I personally think, a good answer. All of the answers got the downvotes though, but not the question. Sometimes, I just don't understand the community here.

Comment: You and me, both. I particularly dislike downvotes without explanation, but my pet peeve is "drive-by" "me too" downvoting, where as soon as you go negative, they pile on the downvotes with no explanation.  Btw, I am working on applying your answer. It is looking good so far

Comment: Yup, this works - but I forgot to mention that the groups nested at different depths in different documents. So, I asked a new question to cover that at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605115/wildcard-search-at-any-nested-depth-using-xml-etree-elementtree/31605886   and have added my own brute force solution - feel fre to improve upon it

Answer (score 1):

First, parse the error definitions into a dictionary:

```
errors = {
    errordef.attrib["name"]: {"id": errordef.attrib.get("id"), "description": errordef.findtext("description")}
    for errordef in root.xpath(".//group[@name='error definitions']/errordef[@name]")
}
```

Then, every time you need to get the error id and description, look it up by code:

```
error_code = root.find("error").attrib["code"]
print(errors.get(error_code, "Unknown Error"))
```

Note that the `xpath()` method is coming from `lxml.etree`. If you are using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, replace `xpath()` with `findall()` - the limited XPath support provided by `xml.etree.ElementTree` is enough for the provided expressions.

Comment: Can I use a wildcard to build the dictionary? I find that groups are named "XXX error definitions", "YYY error definitions", etc. Btw, I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, so calling `findall()`

Comment: It gets worse. The error groups seem to be nested at different depths in different documents. Given the error's title, e.g "unknownDevice", how can I search everything under the root to get the corresponding `id` and `description values?`  I have updated the question to reflect my comments here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the value of description and id for every errordef element, you could do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
dict01={}
tree=ET.parse('grpError.xml')
root=tree.getroot()
print (root)
docExe=root.findall('errordef') #Element reference
dict01=docExe[0].attrib #Store Attributes in dictionary
print (dict01)
print (dict01['id']) #Attributes of an element
print (dict01['name']) #Attributes of an element
print (docExe[0].find('description').text) #Child Elements inside parent Element
```

Output is:

```
<Element 'group' at 0x000001A582EDB4A8>
{'id': '0x11', 'name': 'UnknownDevice'}
0x11
UnknownDevice
Indicated device is unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a selector, though I'm not really sure you can do this with lxml. It has css selector but I don't find anything to select an "id" in the doc...
I only used lxml to remove/add stuff to html. Maybe take a look at scrapy? Using scrapy it would look like this when you loaded your html.

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="0x11"]/text()').extract()
```