# Wildcard search at any nested depth using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a group of XML files which contain entries like

```
   <group name="XXX common string">

      <value val="12" description="a dozen">
         <text>one less than a baker's dozen</text>
      </value>

      <value val="13" description="a baker's dozen">
         <text>One more than a dozen</text>
      </value>

   </group>

   <group name="YYY common string">

      <value val="42" description="the answer">
         <text>What do you get if you multiple 6 by 9?</text>
      </value>

   </group>
```

Is there any simple way, using `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` and

```
    parser = ET.XMLParser()
    parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)

    if (args.info) or (args.diagnostics):
        print('Parsing input file : ' + inputFileName)

    tree = ET.parse(inputFileName, parser=parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
```

to search for only `<group>` elements who#s name contains "common string" for a particular `value val` ?

Important: these groups are nested at different depths in different files.

Answer (score 1):

This was a little difficult, because your own code won't work with the
example data you posted in your question (e.g., nothing there contains
the string `error`, and there are no `id` attributes, and your code
doesn't appear to search for "a particular `value` `val`, which seemed
to be one of your requirements).  But here are a few ideas...

For finding all `group` elements that contain `common string` in the `name` attribute, you could do something like this:

```
>>> matching_groups = []
>>> for group in tree.xpath('//group[contains(@name, "common string")]'):
...   matching_groups.append[group]
...
```

Which given your sample data would result in:

```
>>> print '\n'.join([etree.tostring(x) for x in matching_groups])
<group name="XXX common string">

      <value val="12" description="a dozen">
         <text>one less than a baker's dozen</text>
      </value>

      <value val="13" description="a baker's dozen">
         <text>One more than a dozen</text>
      </value>

   </group>


<group name="YYY common string">

      <value val="42" description="the answer">
         <text>What do you get if you multiple 6 by 9?</text>
      </value>

   </group>
```

If you wanted to limit the results to only `group` elements that
contain `value` element with attribute `val` == `42`, you could try:

```
>>> matching_groups = []
>>> for group in tree.xpath('//group[contains(@name, "common string")][value/@val = "42"]'):
...     matching_groups.append(group)
...
```

Which would yield:

```
>>> print '\n'.join([etree.tostring(x) for x in matching_groups])
<group name="YYY common string">

      <value val="42" description="the answer">
         <text>What do you get if you multiple 6 by 9?</text>
      </value>

   </group>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems were 1) wildcard searching of group name, and 2) the fact that the groups were nested at different levels in different files.

I implemented this brute force approach to build a dictionary of all such error entries in an error named group, anywhere in the file.

I leave it here for posterity and invite more elephant solutions.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    parser = ET.XMLParser()
    parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)

    tree = ET.parse(inputFileName, parser=parser)
    root = tree.getroot()

    args.errorDefinitions = {}
    for element in tree.iter():
        if element.tag == 'group':
            if 'error' in element.get('name').lower():
                if element._children:
                    for errorMessage in element._children[0]._children:
                        args.errorDefinitions[errorMessage.get('name')] = \
                                  {'id':  errorMessage.get('id'), \
                                  'description': element._children[0].text}
```